# Echo is not clearing the session

Tags: session, go, go-echo

I am using [Echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) for my web application. I tried to implement Login and Logout. When I tried to logout, its not clearing the session.  Here is my code:

```
func Logout(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    sess.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   -1,
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
    sess.Values["username"] = ""
    sess.Values["authenticated"] = ""
    sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())
    return c.Redirect(http.StatusSeeOther, "/")
}
```

After logout I checked the session values, its not changing or clearing anything. I am using these packages for session management:

```
"github.com/labstack/echo-contrib/session"
"github.com/gorilla/sessions"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in the client side . Browsers are ignoring Set-Cookie in redirect response when domain of the cookie is localhost.  So I have to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't help that much, what you can do is set the expiration of the cookie with a negative value.

Comment: @YrineuRodrigues Maybe my case is different, so that answer was OK for me.

Comment: Oh, just saw... you asked the question and then you answer and approved your own question.